# How do I try out the new `<execution>` header on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, clang

Saw the `<execution>` header [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t), and wanted to try it out.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- `brew install cmake --HEAD`
- `brew install llvm`

Installed versions:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ --version
clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin


$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.20181204-gb8db7
```

I thought I might have got cmake flags wrong, so tried compiling directly; here's an isolated one-liner that *should* work:

`CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp`

And here's the (stubborn!) error I keep getting:

`fatal error: 'execution' file not found`

The line it's complaining about: `#include <execution>`

Any clues are *much* appreciated!

*Edit:* I see the header is missing from `/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++`, so of *course* it can't work with what I have (and doesn't seem to be present within `experimental` either), is there another recommended way to install this on osx?

Comment: You need C++17 for that, which currently means MSVC only.

Comment: Clang should already have a lot of c++17 support: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: Clang support means nothing if libc++ has no support. Clang can use libstdc++ but that doesn't have execution either (Apr-2019).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I was missing an explicit `-std=c++17` flag (interestingly, `-std=c++2a` doesn't work! Which may be okay, but a bit surprising if you expect *that mode* to be a superset of the c++17 mode)

Anyway, I can confirm that the following works for me just fine:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" \
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ \
-std=c++17 \
foo.cpp
```